Dynamic typescript type based on other fields in a Class?
Consider the following two classes:
export class Node<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> {
  id: string;
  action: T;
  result: ReturnType<T>;

  constructor(id: string, action: T) {
    this.id = id;
    this.action = action;
  }
}

export class Flow {
  nodes: Node<(flow: Flow) => any>[];

  // How would I create a map here that enforces nodes[i].id as the only valid key strings,
  // and nodes[i].result as the corresponding value type?
  context: <help>?

  constructor(nodes: Node<(flow: Flow) => any>[]) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
  }
}

How might I add a context field to the Flow class such that the below code works as indicated?
const flow = new Flow([
  new Node("one", () => 1),
  new Node("two", (flow) => flow.context.one + 1),
]);

flow.context.one; // 1
flow.context.asdasd; // typescript error, missing from node ids


Node must be made more generic to keep track of id, and then Flow must be generic to keep track of the set of Nodes. But for const flow = ... you'll run into TS's limitations with inference as described in ms/TS#47599. It's going to be hard or impossible for TS to infer the type of Flow you're constructing while you're constructing it, so that the flow callback param in the "two" node will already know about "one". You need to refactor to use a builder, or give up on inference; which of those would you like to explore?

Thanks for the info @jcalz! I'm curious about almost everything you mentioned! I think I might be looking for the builder pattern? Would you mind elaborating a bit? Sorry, I'm quite new to typescript (O(hours)).

Take a look at this playground link.  With "give up on inference" you will specifically ask for a Flow<{one: number, two: number}>. With the builder pattern, you make your Flow in steps, starting from an "empty" one (Flow<{}>) through Flow<{one: number}> and then to Flow<{one: number, two: number}>. Each step lets you infer the new piece from the old pieces. Neither way gives you inference of the whole thing at once. So, how should we proceed here? I'm happy to write an answer but I don't want to write a novel. Which approach, if either, meets your needs?

Wow, thank you so very much for that incredibly helpful link! I am looking for the builder pattern, as I would hate for users to have to specify all their types ahead of time. And I think it's a fair assumption at this point in time to only have access to data from previously "built" nodes.

Then I'll write an answer focusing on the builder pattern.

Amazing, I will upvote and mark accepted.

In order for this to possibly work, you'd need Nodes to keep track of not just the action or result type, but also the id. So we'll have to make it more generic like Node<K, T>:
export class Node<K extends PropertyKey, T extends (...args: any[]) => any> {
  id: K;
  action: T;
  declare result: ReturnType<T>;

  constructor(id: K, action: T) {
    this.id = id;
    this.action = action;
  }
}

Then you'll also need Flow to be generic, either in the type of the set of nodes it holds onto, or in the object type of context. I'll choose the latter, so a Flow<T> has a context property of type T:
export class Flow<T extends object> {
  declare nodes: ObjToNode<T>[];
  declare context: T    
  constructor(nodes: ObjToNode<T>[]) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
  }     
}

The ObjToNode<T> type represents the union of Node<?, ?> types in nodes that correspond to T. Here's one way to compute it:
type ObjToNode<T extends object> =
  { [K in keyof T]: Node<K, (flow: Flow<T>) => T[K]> }[keyof T]

This is a distributive object type (as coined in ms/TS#47109), where we compute a mapped type over each property of T, and then index into that type with keyof T to get the union of all the properties within. So ObjToNode<T> is the union of Node<K, (flow: Flow<T>) => T[K]> for each K in keyof T.

That's sufficient for the typings, so conceptually your code would produce a Flow<{one: number, two: number}> and the flow callback parameters in your Node constructor calls would also be that type. Unfortunately such type inference doesn't quite happen properly here:
const flow = new Flow([
  new Node("one", () => 1),
  new Node("two", (flow) => flow.context.one + 1),
  //               ^? (parameter) flow: any
]);
// const flow: Flow<{one: any} & {two: any}>

flow.context.one; // okay
flow.context.asdasd; // error

You get a Flow<{one: any, two: any}>; meaning TypeScript was able to get the keys right, but the property values aren't specific enough. And the flow callback parameter is contextually inferred as just any, which isn't helpful either.  I could try to rewrite Flow so it is generic in the set of Node types, but inference wouldn't happen right there either.  The problem is the simultaneous inference of the flow callback parameter with the whole object. It's a circular/recursive sort of inference involving both generic type argument inference and contextual typing. And TypeScript generally has a hard time with that. It's the subject of microsoft/TypeScript#47599.

One way to proceed is to give up on inference, and just manually specify the expected type like
const flow = new Flow<{ one: number, two: number }>([
  //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  new Node("one", () => 1),
  new Node("two", (flow) => flow.context.one + 1),
]);

That works, and doesn't require any runtime changes to your code. But if you don't want developers to write out their types like this, then you'll need to refactor to a form where inference can happen in well-defined stages instead of all at once.  The most straightforward way to do that is with a builder.

Instead of new Flow([⋯, ⋯, ⋯]), you'd use something like Flow.builder.with(⋯).with(⋯).with(⋯).build(), as shown here:
const flow = Flow.builder
  .with(new Node("one", () => 1))
  .with(new Node("two", flow => flow.context.one + 1))
  //                    ^? (parameter) flow: Flow<{ one: number; }>
  .build();

//^? const flow: Flow<{ one: number; two: number; }>

The idea is that Flow.builder itself would represent an "empty object" Flow<{}>. And then each with() would add a single property to it, where the flow callback parameter at each step represents the Flow<T> type for the previous step. This looks like a ladder, where you climb one rung at a time, from Flow<{}> to Flow<{one: number}> to Flow<{one: number, two: number}>. If you can't refactor that way because, say, one depends on two and two depends on one, then you have a truly circular type and I'd give up on inference entirely. But as long as you can lay out your properties in an order where each property only depends on earlier properties, then this will work.
So now we have to implement Flow.builder. Well, let's define FlowBuilder():
class FlowBuilder<T extends object> {
  nodes: ObjToNode<T>[];
  constructor(nodes: ObjToNode<T>[]) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
  }
  with<K extends PropertyKey, V>(node: Node<K, (flow: Flow<T>) => V>) {
    return new FlowBuilder<{ [P in K | keyof T]: P extends keyof T ? T[P] : V }>(
      [...this.nodes, node] as any
    )
  }
  build(): Flow<T> {
    return new Flow(this.nodes);
  }
}

A FlowBuilder<T> just takes the array of ObjToNode<T> nodes, and the build() method calls the Flow constructor with those nodes.
The with() method is where the important work takes place. It creates a new FlowBuilder with one new node added to the end of the current nodes list. If the new node is of type Node<K, (flow: Flow<T>) => V>, then the returned FlowBuilder is of a type like FlowBuilder<T & Record<K, V>>.  It has one more property than T.  The type I wrote { [P in K | keyof T]: P extends keyof T ? T[P] : V } is effectively equivalent to T & Record<K, V>, but it is generally prettier, and will display as {a: 0, b: 1, c: 2} instead of {} & Record<"a", 0> & Record<"b", 1> & Record<"c", 2>.  In either case, TypeScript doesn't understand ObjToNode<T> in the arbitrary generic case to understand that [...this.nodes, node] is of the right type for either T & Record<K, V> or { [P in K | keyof T]:  ⋯ } so the implementation uses a type assertion to the any type to silence type errors.
Note that with() creates new FlowBuilders instead of modifying this.  That lets you reuse FlowBuilders with impunity. A FlowBuilder<T> will stay a FlowBuilder<T> forever; it will not mutate into a FlowBuilder<T & Record<K, V>> under your nose.  In particular, you only need one FlowBuilder<{}> to exist, and you can reuse it as often as you want. In fact, let's just create one and make it a static property of Flow:
export class Flow<T extends object> {
  // ⋯ same impl as before ⋯ //
  static builder = new FlowBuilder<{}>([]);
}

So now you can write Flow.builder.with(⋯).with(⋯).with(⋯).⋯.build() to get your strongly-typed Flows, and you don't need to worry about Flow.builder itself being modified.

So there you go.  To recap: you need to make Node more generic and Flow generic, and then to deal with TypeScript's inference limitations you either need to manually specify type arguments or write a builder.
Playground link to code

Far and away the most helpful SO answer I've ever received. Thank you @jcalz!
